# How to stop the execution or throw an error in scala play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm developing a scala application with play framework, but i got something strange.
i can't stop the execution nor throwing an error in order to send a response for the client, it always continue the code and it always returning okay, however i made a dummy function that it should return a bad request but unfortunately it is returning OK here is what i wrote. any help will be appreciated

```
def foo(locale: String, orderId: Int) = Action { implicit request => {
 val x=4+7;
if(x==11){
BadRequest(JsonHelper.convertToJson("Bad bad it is really bad "))
}
OK(JsonHelper.convertToJson("Well Done"))
}
}
```

the above code returning OK Well done.

Answer (score 4):

To make your code return a `BadRequest`, add an `else`:

```
def foo(locale: String, orderId: Int) = Action { implicit request => {
  val x = 4 + 7;
  if (x == 11)
    BadRequest(JsonHelper.convertToJson("Bad bad it is really bad "))
  else // <---
    OK(JsonHelper.convertToJson("Well Done"))
}}
```

Comment: i can't use if else because in my case there are about 6 validations should be proceed so if i want to use if else i will have 6 if else , i think it is a really bad practice what do you prefer ?

Comment: That's not a bad practice, and that's what need to be done

Comment: @HabooltakAna, although it is not typically used in Scala code, there is still `return` in Scala and you can use it to return value from where you want. But unless you are fighting deep `if` nesting I would suggest against it because in some cases it has behavior unexpected by users of other languages (see for example [here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)). And if you do fight nesting - probably you should split you method into a bunch of smaller ones.

Comment: @SergGr thanks but actually i coudn't return anything, even i returned null i it throws an exception

Comment: @HabooltakAna, because of unusual semantics return is often implemented via an exception but that exception should be caught inside the same method by a catch generated by the compiler. Do you say that you can see this exception outside of the method? Could you provide a stack trace? I believe it would be a bug in a compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your if without curly braces.

refered to this link :https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/control-structures.html#curly-braces

> if - Omit braces if you have an else clause. Otherwise, surround the
>   contents with curly braces even if the contents are only a single
>   line.

so you can just suuround the BadRequest with curly braces or add an else statement between your Bad and OK instruction. Be careful, don't forget the indentation !

edit 20/12/2017 >> un scala the last instruction is implicitly returned. Your last instruction is OK, so it returns OK.

Add explicit return statement in your if block or add an else statement.

Comment: "it doesn't work" — error message? unexpected behavior? or what?

Comment: the same problem i mean

Comment: @HabooltakAna can you edit your first message with your new code ?